# PHP insert a value into a loop using continue

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how to insert a value when a specific argument is satisfied then will continue printing the value inside a loop, I was looking at `continue` statement of PHP and found this example.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; ++$i) {
    if ($i == 2)
     echo "Checkpoint";
     echo $i;
        continue;
    print "$i\n";
}
```

And this works! as what i want to achieve, the output is below.

> 01Checkpoint234

Now I am attempting to re-create on my script but cannot get it to work.

```
 <?php foreach($v as $key => $value) {?>


    <?php  if ($key < 50) ?>
       {
        "key": <?= $key;?>,
        "Volume": <?= $value;?>,
        "expenses": 0,
        "color": 'green',
        "lineColor": 'green'
       } ,

       <?php continue;?>

       {
        "key": 50,
        "Volume": 0,
        "expenses": 0,
        "color": 'green',
        "lineColor": 'green'
       } ,

       {
        "key": <?= $key;?>,
        "Volume": <?= $value;?>,
        "expenses": 0,
        "color": 'green',
        "lineColor": 'green'
       } ,


    <?php }?>
```

My output is below

```
   {
    "key": 50,
    "Volume": 0,
    "expenses": 0,
    "color": 'green',
    "lineColor": 'green'

  } ,
    {
    "key": 39,
    "Volume": 4,
    "expenses": 1.7668,
    "color": 'green',
    "lineColor": 'green',

    } ,

    {
    "key": 50,
    "Volume": 0,
    "expenses": 0,
    "color": 'green',
    "lineColor": 'green'  
   } ,
     {
    "key": 38,
    "Volume": 5,
    "expenses": 1.739,
    "color": 'green',
    "lineColor": 'green',

    } ,
```

What I want to do is when the key is (<) less than 50 I want to insert an element with a "Key" of 50 then will continue to print what key that is less than 50, any suggestion would be great.

Comment: You show an `if` with what looks like more than one line that should kick in. Get in the habit of surrounding *all the code you need to have happen* in `{` and `}`, even if it's one line: right now, your code goes "if ($i == 2) echo "Checkpoint";` and then goes on to the rest of the code so your `echo $i;` and `continue` will **always** trigger. You'll never, ever, reach `print "$i\n";` because `continue` will always trigger.

Comment: Not sure how you achieve the output as in the code you show, expenses is always set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need continue for this.  Continue will start the loop over at the next iteration, skipping any code after it.  This code will print all items, but if the key is less than 50, it will create an extra item with key of 50.  Is that what you wanted to do ?

```
<?php foreach ($v as $key => $value) {

    if ($key < 50) { ?>
       {
        "key": 50,
        "Volume": 0,
        "expenses": 0,
        "color": 'green',
        "lineColor": 'green'
       } ,
    <?php } ?>
   {
    "key": <?= $key;?>,
    "Volume": <?= $value;?>,
    "expenses": 0,
    "color": 'green',
    "lineColor": 'green'
   } ,
<?php } ?>
```